# How to empty subdirectory with bash?

Tags: bash

say in `/root/parent` there are many directories named `c1`, `c2`, `c3` etc, in which there may be a `tar` directory. now I want to empty `tar` if it exists. How?(one line command best)

for example:

```
/root/parent/c1/tar/a.py
/root/parent/c2/b.py
/root/parent/c2/c.py
/root/parent/c3/tar/
/root/parent/c3/c.py
/root/parent/c4/tar/a.py
/root/parent/c4/tar/b.py
```

will be:

```
/root/parent/c1/tar/
/root/parent/c2/b.py
/root/parent/c2/c.py
/root/parent/c3/tar/
/root/parent/c3/c.py
/root/parent/c4/tar/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cd /root/parent
find */tar -mindepth 1 -delete
```

This will remove all the entries below `tar/` sub-directories but will leave out `tar/`.

Comment: Dude, you are the best.